# Fail to create string property, how can I know which records are problematic?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I'm trying to create property in the following way:

```
CREATE PROPERTY Entity.entity_name STRING
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The database contains some schema-less data in the property
>   'Entity.entity_name' that is not compatible with the type STRING. Fix
>   those records and change the schema again

How can I know which records are problematic? I have over 300,000 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query

```
select @rid from Entity where entity_name.type() <> "STRING limit -1"
```

Example:

I created these records

[image]

[image]

[image]